# Angular.js Service Factory module...return inner code as a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am really new to angular.js. This is my first Service that I wrote. It takes a json object and updates the scope of the controller. I'm a little confused on it though...I think I am supposed to wrap the inner code of sseListener and return it as a function, but I am not sure how exactly I would write that and why I need to return it as a function.

Also, if I inject this service to several controllers, would that multiply the event listeners? I only want to have one event listener.

```
one@demo ~/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/scripts $ cat services/sse_listen.js 
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('sseListener', function () {
    var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
         event = Object.keys(result)[0];
         switch(event) {
             case "cpuResult":
                 cpuUpdate(result);
             break;
         }
    });
}
```

---

```
one@demo ~/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/scripts $ cat controllers/main.js 
'use strict';

angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $location, $document) {
    console.log("s");
});

angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('cpuCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.apiTimeStamp = "";
    $scope.infoReceived = "";
    $scope.last15 = "";
    $scope.last5 = "";
    $scope.lastMinute = "";

    var cpuUpdate = function (result) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
            $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
            $scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data
            $scope.last5 = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data
            $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['15'].data
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling cpuUpdate directly (it's not clear to me how your factory gets a reference to this function), it would be better to use $rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, data), and react to the event in your controller. Also, you should return an object from factories, but since you don't need to inject this anywhere, it's best to put it in an app.run. Here's how I think your code should with the changes I mentioned:

```
angular.module('monitorApp').
    run(function ($rootScope) { //Inject the $rootScope
        var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');

        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
             event = Object.keys(result)[0];
             switch(event) {
                 case "cpuResult":
                     // Broadcast the event with data
                     $rootScope.$broadcast('$cpuResult', result);
                 break;
             }
        });
    }).
    controller('cpuCtrl', function($scope)){
        $scope.apiTimeStamp = "";
        $scope.infoReceived = "";
        $scope.last15 = "";
        $scope.last5 = "";
        $scope.lastMinute = "";

        // Need to pass the event to cpuUpdate,
        var cpuUpdate = function (e, result) { 
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
                $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
                $scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data
                $scope.last5 = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data
                $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['15'].data
            });
        };

        //Listen for the event, call cpuUpdate when caught
        $scope.$on('$cpuResult', cpuUpdate);
    });
```

Comment: Is this with returning an object from my factory? I don't see a return  functionName in sseListener

Comment: Whoops, I forgot that part, I'll fix it.

Comment: Oh...ok...I wouldn't want to return `var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');` `source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {}`? if no, why?

Comment: You only need to return an object exposing members that you want to access by injecting the factory anyway. You might want to return {'source': source} so that you could check the status of the event listener.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, since you're not injecting this anywhere, I think it's best to put this code in an app.run rather than a factory. I've modified the code accordingly.